# Alternating zeta function equation for powers greater than $1$.

Tags: calculus

Playing around with wolfram alpha, I'm noticing that for an $s$ greater than $1$:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^s}=\frac{4^{\frac{1}{2}(s-1)}-1}{4^{\frac{1}{2}(s-1)}} \zeta(s)$$

For all my tries so far. How can I derive this/prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_n(-1)^{n-1}\frac 1 {n^s}=-\sum_{n}\frac 1{(2n)^s}\color{green}{-\sum_{n}\frac 1{(2n)^s}}\color{red}{+\sum_{n}\frac 1{(2n)^s}}+\sum_n\frac1{(2n+1)^s}$$
$$=-\frac 2{2^s}\sum_n\frac 1{n^s}+\sum_n\frac 1{n^s}=\zeta(s)\left(1-\frac1{4^{\frac 12(s-1)}}\right)$$
$$=\left(\frac{4^{\frac 12(s-1)}-1}{4^{\frac 12(s-1)}}\right)\zeta(s)$$

Comment: Sorry but shouldn't there be a negative one of the even zeta functions. Also I don't really understand how you get from the first line to the second line can you explain please.

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla in the first line, since the power of $-1$ is $n-1$, then the terms are negative when $n$ is even, and positive when odd. The colored terms cancel each other out. The term before the green is for the even the one after the red is for the odd. Notice that the first two terms are equal so you add them up. The last two terms are the same sum, one for odd, one for even, so yet get the zeta function. Then you manipulate to get the final answer.

Comment: Sorry, my apologies. Did not see that negative out in front. Your approach is very clever. Thanks!.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $s>1$. By the absolute convergence, one may write
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n^s}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac1{(2k)^s}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{-1}{(2k-1)^s}=\frac1{2^s}\zeta(s)-\zeta(s)\left(1-\frac1{2^s}\right)
$$ that is
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n^s}=(2^{1-s}-1)\zeta(s)
$$ as you have observed.

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla You are right, in fact I notice that I've considered $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n^s}$ rather than $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^s}$, so my result is just minus times yours. What you have to note here, is that $n=1,2,3,\cdots$ is the union of $n=2,4,6,\cdots$ and $n=1,3,5\cdots$.

Comment: Thanks. After carful thought  I think you got: $(1-2^{s})\zeta(s)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2s-1)^k}$ from noting that both the even series and the odd series must some up to be the regimen zeta function, but the even series is $\frac{1}{2^s}\zeta(s)$ so what must be left is $(1-\frac{1}{2^s})\zeta(s)$. Is this what what you had in mind or is it something simpler?

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla Yes, exactly.