# How to compute $\lim\limits_{s\rightarrow0^{+}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n^{s}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Recently I have been discussing the question with my classmates. Since the partial sum of $(-1)^{n}$ is uniformly bounded and $\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n^{s}}$ decreases to $0$ uniformly on any closed interval in $(0,+\infty)$, we know $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n^{s}}$ is continuous on $(0,+\infty)$. However, we found it diffucult to compute $\lim\limits_{s\rightarrow0^{+}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n^{s}}$. I am not sure whether we can use the Riemann-zeta function $\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{s}}$ since the definition of $\zeta(s)$ around $0$ depends on the analytic extension instead of the sum itself. Any advice will be helpful.

Comment: What's the first term of the series $\Sigma_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^s}$?

Comment: note that $\eta(s)=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n^{s}}, \Re s >0$ with uniform converges on compacts say, so if by your limit you mean $\lim_{s \to 0^+}(-\eta(s))$ then that is easily seen to be $-1/2$

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. I have edited the problem and $n$ starts from 1 now.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1882773/42969

Comment: A (good) [general approach](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2866902), and an [elementary](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1993419) one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that for any $s>0$
$$-\eta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n^s}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{\Gamma(s)}\int_0^\infty t^{s-1}e^{-nt}dt=\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^N\int_0^\infty (-1)^nt^{s-1}e^{-nt}dt$$
Next, consider for any fixed $N$ the set of functions $f_N(t)=\sum_{n=1}^N(-1)^ne^{-nt}t^{s-1}=\frac{-1+(-1)^{N+1}e^{-Nt}}{e^t+1}t^{s-1}$

$|f_N(t)|$ is dominated by the integrable function $f(t)=\frac{2t^{s-1}}{e^t+1}$ on $[0;\infty)$. Therefore, by the dominated convergence theorem (DCT),
$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\int_0^\infty f_N(t)dt=\int_0^\infty\Big(\lim_{N\to\infty}f_N(t)\Big)dt$$
and
$$-\eta(s)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^N(-1)^n\int_0^\infty t^{s-1}e^{-nt}dt=\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}\int_0^\infty \Big(\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^N(-1)^nt^{s-1}e^{-nt}\Big)dt$$
$$=-\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}\int_0^\infty\frac{t^{s-1}}{e^t+1}dt\overset{IBP}{=}-\,\frac{1}{s\Gamma(s)}\frac{t^s}{e^t+1}\,\bigg|_0^\infty-\,\frac{1}{s\Gamma(s)}\int_0^\infty\frac{t^se^t}{(e^t+1)^2}dt$$
$$-\eta(s)=-\frac{1}{\Gamma(1+s)}\int_0^\infty\frac{t^se^t}{(e^t+1)^2}dt$$
Leading $s\to 0$, we can use again the DCT, and take the limit under the integral sign. Given that $\lim_{s\to 0}\Gamma(1+s)=1$,
$$\lim_{s\to0^+}\big(-\eta(s)\big)=-\,\int_0^\infty\frac{e^t}{(e^t+1)^2}dt=-\,\frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$f(s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n^{s}}=\left(2^{1-s}-1\right) \zeta (s)=-\eta(s)$$ Expanded as a series around $s=0^+$ (have  look [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirichletEtaFunction.html))
$$f(s)=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}  \log \left(\frac{2}{\pi
   }\right)s+O\left(s^2\right)$$ which is quite good up to $s\sim \frac 14$

$$\int_0^{\frac 14}\Bigg[\left(2^{1-s}-1\right) \zeta (s)-\left(-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}  \log \left(\frac{2}{\pi
   }\right)s \right)\Bigg]^2\,ds=1.906\times 10^{-7}$$